# Evaluate a limit of a complex function in the form of 0/0

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I have to evaluate the following limit:

$$
\lim _{z \rightarrow-i} \frac{z^{11}-i}{z^7-i} 
$$

By direct substitution, I get a result of
$$
\lim _{z \rightarrow-i} \frac{z^{11}-i}{z^7-i} = \frac{0}{0}
$$

And I tried to use factorization to cancel the terms and rationalization with conjugates but they seem not to be working here.

I am now wondering if there is any other way to evaluate the limit or demonstrate that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Hint: let $z=ix$ then $\lim _{z \to -i} \frac{z^{11}-i}{z^7-i} = \lim _{x \to -1} \frac{x^{11}+1}{x^7+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
z^7-i&=z^7-(-i)^7\\
&=(z+i)\left(z^6-i z^5-z^4+i z^3+z^2-i z-1\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
z^{11}-i&=z^{11}-(-i)^{11}\\
&=(z+i)\left(z^{10}-i z^9-z^8+i z^7+z^6-i z^5-z^4+i z^3+z^2-i z-1\right),
\end{align}
you have
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to-i}\frac{z^{11}-i}{z^7-i}&=\lim_{z\to-i}\frac{z^{10}-i z^9-z^8+i z^7+z^6-i z^5-z^4+i z^3+z^2-i z-1}{z^6-i z^5-z^4+i z^3+z^2-i z-1}\\
&=\frac{-11}{-7}\\
&=\frac{11}7.
\end{align}